# Android Studio 3.2 cannot debug when including native code as part of project

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, native-code

Using Android Studio 3.2, I have created a new, default, project which includes c++ support.

When I run, non-debug, the application on my android device the application runs. No problems with run.

However, I cannot debug my app when running the debugger. The android device shows the message 'Waiting for Debugger' that never disappears. Am I missing a setting?

Also, Android Studio reports an IDE Fatal Error with an exception in the plugin Android NDK Support. Is there a location where Android Studio would have logs with more details for this exception?

Removing

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

from the app build.gradle and removing the reference to the JNI function call allows the debugger to function and connect albeit with no native code.

What am I missing?

My Setup:

- Windows 7
- Android Studio 3.2
- LLDB 3.1 (I have also tried LLDB 3.0 and 2.3)
- CMake 3.6.4111459

Here are the options selected when creating the project using the wizard:

Create Android Project

- Include C++ Support selected

Target Android Devices

- Phone and Tablet selected
- API 21: Android 5.0 (Lollipop) selected

Add an Activity to Mobile

- Empty Activity

Customize C++ Support

- C++ Standard set to C++ 11